# How to add a dot notification not opened in Swift?

Tags: swift, notifications, icons

I am trying to add a small dot at the left of a cell when a notification in my app has not been opened yet. I have been trying to figure it out the name of that indicator, but I haven't found it yet.

This is exactly what I am searching for, the blue dot at the left of the cell

[image]

Does any of you know if that 'icon' has a name?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using iOS 13+ you can use `SFSymbols`:

```
Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```